# HTTP status code When there is a java.sql.SQLException

Tags: rest, http, datasource

I am creating a REST api which integrates an SQL Database. I would like to know what http status the REST api would return when there is a java.sql.SQLException?

In general, what http status would get return when the data source, including Database, JMS, etc., throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to a SQLException from a condition that you don't expect to happen, such as a direct problem with the DB connection, I would say that falls into the status 500 category. Something actually went wrong server side that you had no control over.

Comment: Can you be specific? 500 is for internal server error, which conveys that there is a problem with my REST api, actually it is not.

Comment: 500 wouldn't necessarily be indicating a problem with your API unless it was a similar, unrecoverable situation you maybe had no control over. By saying 500, you are indicating that something really bad happened internally that wasn't caused by a bad request from the client. You may want to customize the entity or message that comes back with a 500 if that's needed to provide a more user friendly message, if that is a requirement.